# JQUERY UI Slider With Arrows & String Map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

In short, I have a JQUERY UI Slider. The values are all based on a string map (array). The map is then split to display 2 separate values when you slide. This all works 100%. I now have two arrows on both sides of the slider that is suppose to do the same thing, slide left / right and increment / decrements. Those also does the job.

But, how do I (when clicking my images left / right) get the value from my map array and update my text controls?

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var valMap =
                [
                "2500#2000","2500#4000","2500#6000","2500#15000",
                "3200#2000","3200#4000","3200#6000","3200#15000",
                "3500#0",
                "4000#2000","4000#4000","4000#6000","4000#15000",
                ];

            var s = $("#slider").slider({
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: valMap.length,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var curVal = valMap[ui.value].split('#');
                    var basicVal = curVal[0];
                    var volVal = curVal[1];                   

                    if (volVal == '0') {
                        $("#vol").fadeOut("slow");
                        $("#volLbl").fadeOut("slow");
                        var premTot = ((parseFloat(basicVal)) / 11).toFixed(2);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#vol").fadeIn("slow");
                        $("#volLbl").fadeIn("slow");
                        var premTot = ((parseFloat(basicVal) * parseFloat(volVal)) / 14800).toFixed(2);
                    }
                    $("#basic").val("R " + basicVal);
                    $("#vol").val("R " + volVal);
                    $("#prem").val("R " + premTot);
                }
            });
            $("#imgPrev").click(function () {
                s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
            });
            $("#imgNext").click(function () {
                s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
            });
        });
  </script>

<div>
    <p>
        <label>Basic Excess:</label><input type="text" id="basic" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        <br />
        <label id="volLbl">Voluntary Excess:</label><input type="text" id="vol" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        <br />
        <label>Premium:</label><input type="text" id="prem" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
 <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td style="width:26px;"><img src="Images/Previous_24x24.png" id="imgPrev" /></td>
     <td><div id="slider"></div></td>
     <td style="width:26px;"><img src="Images/Next_24x24.png" id="imgNext" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation done in the `slide` event is absolutely the same you need to do when `#imgNext` and `#imgPrev`click events are called, what was being done is that the value of the slider was being updated, but not actually firing `slide` event, so an approach would be to make a function out of the code from `slide` event and call it in both cases, for example:

```
$(function () {
        var valMap =
            [
            "2500#2000","2500#4000","2500#6000","2500#15000",
            "3200#2000","3200#4000","3200#6000","3200#15000",
            "3500#0",
            "4000#2000","4000#4000","4000#6000","4000#15000",
            ];
        var basicVal, volVal, premTot;

        var s = $("#slider").slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: valMap.length,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                calculate(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#imgPrev").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
            calculate(s.slider('value'));
        });
        $("#imgNext").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
            calculate(s.slider('value'));
        });

    function calculate(value){
      curVal = valMap[value].split('#');
      basicVal = curVal[0];
      volVal = curVal[1];                   

      if (volVal == '0') {
          $("#vol").fadeOut("slow");
          $("#volLbl").fadeOut("slow");
          var premTot = ((parseFloat(basicVal)) / 11).toFixed(2);
      }
      else {
          $("#vol").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#volLbl").fadeIn("slow");
          var premTot = ((parseFloat(basicVal) * parseFloat(volVal)) / 14800).toFixed(2);
      }
      $("#basic").val("R " + basicVal);
      $("#vol").val("R " + volVal);
      $("#prem").val("R " + premTot);
    }
});
```

The parameter to the new `calculate` function is the selected index. Perhaps you will want to set the text controls when page is first loaded also.

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/YE5v5/